# Android Cardview using recycleview with header and details

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I would like to create a list of cards using recycle view but am having trouble understanding how to create the CustomAdapter and Layout to do the card details. See the homeData list for the data I am being provided. I am able to create the address header of the card but not sure how to handle the details. The headers should be treated like categories as in I would only use one address per card but need to list each month per address.

Also, it is possible there could be more than one row of months in the details.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

```
List<HomeAvailability> homeData = new ArrayList<>(); 
    homeData.add(new HomeAvailability("1111 Main St", "Jun"));
    homeData.add(new HomeAvailability("1111 Main St", "Jul"));
    homeData.add(new HomeAvailability("1111 Main St", "Aug"));
    homeData.add(new HomeAvailability("1111 Park St", "Jul"));
    homeData.add(new HomeAvailability("2222 Park St", "Aug"));
    homeData.add(new HomeAvailability("2222 Oregon St", "Oct"));
    homeData.add(new HomeAvailability("1111 Oregon St", "Nov"));
    homeData.add(new HomeAvailability("1111 Oregon St", "Dec"));
    homeData.add(new HomeAvailability("1111 Oregon St", "Jan"));
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

     MainAdapter mAdapter = new MainAdapter(homeData);
     mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView address;
        TextView month; 

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            address = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            //month = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.month);
        }
    } 

    List<HouseAvailability> mDataset;

    public CustomAdapter(List<HouseAvailability> myDataset) {
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,
                                               int viewType) { 
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);  
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int i) { 
       holder.address.setText(mDataset.get(i).address); 
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

card_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_below="@id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

         //Months here?

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: do you have any control over `homeData`? can you change how the list is being created? if so, you should instead create a list of items, with one entry per address, each holding a list of months

Comment: Yes, I could manipulate the data if that is recommended. I didnt want to start doing a bunch of loops to prepare the data if there was a better way to work with the adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to achieve your goal with your current data set, but I recommend you to make another data set which has one-and-only address data per item.

Anyway if you wanna do it with your current set you have to modify `getItemCount()`, `getItemType()`, `onCreateViewHolder()`, `onBindViewHolder()`.

**Code Example**

(I haven't tested this code, it's handwritten.)

Assume your data class has modified like this way:

```
class HouseAvailability
{
    public String address;
    public ArrayList<String> monthList;
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView address;
        TextView month; 

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            address = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            month = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.month);
        }

        public void bindData(HouseAvailability data) {
            this.address.setText(data.address);
            String monthStr = "";
            for(int i=0; i<data.monthList.size(); i++) {
                monthStr += data.monthList.get(i);
                if(i<data.monthList.size()-1) {
                    if(i%4 == 3)
                        monthStr += "\n"
                    else
                        monthStr += "  "
                }
            }
            this.month.setText(monthStr);
        }
    } 

    List<HouseAvailability> mDataset;

    public CustomAdapter(List<HouseAvailability> myDataset) {
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,
                                               int viewType) { 
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);  
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int i) { 
       holder.bindData(mDataset.get(i)); 
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

And XML part:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_below="@id/address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You can modify the details as you wish.

Comment: If I modify the data set as suggested could you show me how the CustomAdapter and XML should look?

Comment: @Mark_1955 How do you want your month texts to be shaped if they exceed a line? grid view, side-scroll, or just line break?

Comment: if there was 5 months for an address the 5th month would be on a new detail row in the card body. The individual card would also get vertically taller due to it showing two rows. Same rule would apply for 9 months as in there would be 3 rows below the address header.

Comment: To answer your question i think line-break. I was thinking table rows but not sure if those exist in android (xml).

Comment: @Mark_1955 It's possible to apply table to month list. Search `TableLayout` and plenty of data is waiting for you :)